# react-ace + flexlayout-react: Ace editor keeps resetting

Tags: reactjs, ace-editor

I have a `FlexLayout` (from [flexlayout-react](https://github.com/caplin/FlexLayout)) which contains an `AceEditor` (from [react-ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace)). For testing I added a `Test` component as well.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import FlexLayout from 'flexlayout-react';
import AceEditor from 'react-ace';

// display an Ace editor (here with fixed size)
const Editor = () => {
  return (
    <AceEditor
      width="200px"
      height="200px"
      value="foo"
    />
  );
}

// an increment button, just something simple stateful
const Test = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

// two columns for editor and test component
const model = FlexLayout.Model.fromJson({
  global: {},
  borders: [],
  layout: {
    type: 'row',
    weight: 50,
    children: [
      {
        type: 'tabset',
        weight: 50,
        selected: 0,
        children: [
          {
            type: 'tab',
            name: 'A',
            component: 'editor',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: 'tabset',
        weight: 50,
        selected: 0,
        children: [
          {
            type: 'tab',
            name: 'B',
            component: 'test',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});

const factory = node => {
  switch (node.getComponent()) {
    case 'editor': {
      return <Editor />;
    }
    case 'test': {
      return <Test />;
    }
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

// display the flex layout
const Ide = () => {
  return (
    <FlexLayout.Layout
      model={model}
      factory={factory}
    />
  );
};

// render everything
ReactDOM.render(
  <Ide />,
  document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

So what's going on?

Whenever the `FlexLayout` state changes (focus changed, dragging the divider, changing width), the text of the Ace editor is reset to `foo`. In contrast, the value of `Test` is preserved. Without the `FlexLayout`, the problem goes away.

So there seems to be a curious interaction between the two components, but I'm too inexperienced with React to figure it out. How would I go about debugging this? What are common avenues of approach with such an issue? Or any concrete ideas where the error is in this specific situation?